# Convex curve, asymptote

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, convex-geometry

How can a convex increasing curve have an horizontal asymptote?
I read that in a paper, but I just can't see how this is possible.

The situation is the the following: $a,b$ are some constants, we have a differential equation

$z^{'}(t)=(a+b z^3) f(t)$

where $f(t)$ is known.

Let $z_0$ be the initial value for $t_0$.

By seperation of variables:

$F(z)= \int\limits_{z_0}^z \dfrac{ds}{a+b s^3} =  \int\limits_{t_0}^t f(\tau) d \tau =X(t)$

and we get a solution $z = F^{-1}(X)$.

Now the paper says: The graph of $F(z)$ in the sector $z \geq 0,
X \geq 0$ of the Cartesian plane $(z,X)$ is a convex curve tarting at $(t_0 ,z_ 0)$ and increasing towards the asymptote

$M= \int\limits_{z_0}^{\infty} \dfrac{ds}{a+b s^3}$

I also don't understand why this is a convex graph.

Comment: $e^x{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: @user804886 nice! post it as an answer

Comment: @alphaomega I might in a few minutes. I suspect that the question may be updated to specify $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is finite.

Comment: Sorry, in the paper it says the function is increasing towards the asymptote but that's not the case for $e^x$, is it?

Comment: @JamesA That's not convex.

Comment: Well, maybe I should edit the question and tell more details

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ positive?

Comment: yes, they are positive

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a convex non-decreasing curve, and $f$ has a horizontal asymptote given by the line $y=c$ so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=c$, then $f$ is a horizontal line.

Proof:

The line segment between two points on a convex curve has to lie above or on the curve.

Since $f$ is non-decreasing, there does not exist an $x$ such that $f(x)>c$.

Suppose that there exists a point $x$ such that $f(x)<c$. The height of the midpoint of the line segment from $(x,f(x))$ to $(x',f(x'))$ is at most $\frac{f(x)+c}2$. As the curve cannot go above this line segment, $f\left(\frac{x+x'}2\right)\leq \frac{f(x)+c}2$. No matter how large $x'$ gets, the curve never goes above $\frac{f(x)+c}2$ and can never approach the line $y=c$.

Therefore $f(x)=c$ for all $x$.

Comment: Well, thanks! But I still don't understand what is meant in the paper..

Comment: Maybe the author meant to say that $F(z)$ is a *concave* curve.